# How to prove this version of Urysohn's Lemma using the usual version

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory

I'm trying to prove the Urysohn's lemma that is presented in Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis using the usual version of the Urysohn's Lemma (with normal space ...). Here is the Rudin's Version:

"Suppose $X$ is a locally compact Hausdorff space, $V$ is open in $X$, $K \subset V$ and compact. Then there is a function $f:X \rightarrow [0,1]$ such that $f(K)=1$, $ suppf \subset V$ , $suppf$ is compact and $f$ is continuous."

The first thing that i've done was to consider $Y$ the one point compactification of $X$ . $Y$ is compact and Hausdorff , so $Y$ is normal. $K$ and $Y-V$ are closed and disjoint sets in $Y$, then we can use the usual Urysohn's lemma and we have a function $F:Y \rightarrow [0,1]$ with $F(Y-V)=0$ and $F(K)=1$.
The problem is that don't know if $suppF \subset V$ . I'm probably missing something, because for me $suppF \subset \overline{V}$ and i can't see how to shrink it to $V$. Is there any hope for my demonstration?

Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 3):

Really sorry , I've already corrected that. Since $Y$ is normal we can have a open set $U$ such that $K \subset U$ and $\overline{U} \subset V$ . Taking $U \bigcap X$ and using the regular version of the Urysohn lemma, we can carry on the proof that i sketched in my question.

Comment: You don’t need to intersect $U$ with $X$: $U\subseteq\operatorname{cl}_YU\subseteq V\subseteq X$, so $U\subseteq X$ anyway. Otherwise the argument is fine.